# Keep on getting Unauthorize Web API

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, http-status-code-401

I have a project, It's a web application that requires Windows Authentication.

I've setup an Active Directory at home using my NAS virtualization. Then I've created a VMWare Server for IIS which is a member of that domain on my desktop which I also use for development. I've created the Web API and installed it into that VMWare server. When I call a routine directly, it works and return results but when I use the Web API routine from my javascript web application I keep on getting 401 error. I then put the code on the IIS server and the web application works.

I've seen a lot of solutions like changing the sequence of the Provider in IIS Authentication. Added Everyone read/write permission on the folders. I've also added entry on the web.config. But none of them work.

*****Update as per request on the comment *****

Below is when I run directly from Web API

[image]

Calling the Web API from Javascript
[image]

[image]

Here's the error I'm getting
[image]
[image]

Just FYI, I tried running the web api from Visual Studio on the same machine but also with 401 error

[image]

Is there anything I could add to AD to make my development machine as trusted?

********************A new issue after the code change **********
[image]

****************Another Update******
This is definitely weird, so I installed Fiddler 4 to see what's going on. But still no luck.

Then I made changes on the IIS HTTP Response Header

[image]

[image]

The weird thing is when I run Fiddler the error is gone but when I close it it comes back.

Comment: A 401 response is the normal first step in Windows Authentication. It is then up to the application to repeat the request including credentials. Can you show the code you are using to make the request? The is usually a way to make this happen automatically, if it's not doing it now.

Comment: 401 is a basic challenge response for your server. When you access windows authentication, server will return 401 and web browser will prompt for windows credential. So do you mean that you could access the web api via web browser but fail when you call it from javascript?

Comment: @JokiesDing, that's correct. On the same browser, when I run the web api it shows the result but when it's from the javascript that's when the 401 issue occurs.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, I've added an update as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1. A 401 response is a normal first step to Windows Authentication. The client is then expected to resend the request with credentials. AJAX requests don't do this automatically unless you tell it to.

To tell it to send credentials in a cross-domain request (more on that later), you need to set the [`withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) option when you make the request in JavaScript.

With jQuery, that looks like this:

```js
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
}).then(callback);
```

2. These problems pop up when the URL in the address bar of the browser is different than the URL of the API you are trying to connect to in the JavaScript. Browsers are *very* picky about when this is allowed. These are called "cross-domain requests", or "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" (CORS).

It looks at the protocol, domain name and port. So if the website is `http://localhost:8000`, and it's making an AJAX request to `http://localhost:8001`, that is still considered a cross-domain request.

When a cross-domain AJAX request is made, the browser first sends an OPTIONS request to the URL, which contains the URL of the website that's making the request (e.g. `http://localhost:8000`). The API is expected to return a response with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that says whether the website making the request is allowed to.

If you are not planning on sending credentials, then the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header can be `*`, meaning that the API allows anyone to call it.

However, if you need to send credentials, like you do, you cannot use `*`. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must specifically contain the domain (and port) of your webpage, and the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` must be set to `true`. For example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

It's a bit of a pain in the butt, yes. But it's necessary for security.

You can read more about CORS here: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Gabriel, the error disappeared but I got different error (I'll update on my post). The other question is that, when I run the same code in our corporate domain it works without any additions. Only have issue when I run it on my domain

Comment: I just want to add that I'm just running a local HTML file to test this.

Comment: You will need to fix the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You will have to specify the exact protocol, domain, and port of the site you are running from (even if local). For example: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000` The browser won't send credentials otherwise.

Comment: when you say fix it? Is it on the Web API? IIS? or on the javascript. I just don't understand why this code works on our company domain and I have all these issues in my domain. I'm wondering if I'm missing something on the Active Directory Level. I've contacted the IT guys who created my work server and they told me they didn't do anything special on that server. I even tried making it like for like but still no luck.

Comment: I updated my answer with more details. The short version is that you need to change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to contain the exact website that you are calling it from. [You cannot use a wildcard.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Credentialed_requests_and_wildcards)

Comment: what I don't understand is that. using my work machine, I never have issues with CORS. I'm running the same code (with different server address) but it doesn't have this issue. I'm wondering if there's a browser setting or a windows policy that automatically send the credential.

Comment: They site also needs to be listed in the Trusted Sites in the Internet Options in Windows (for IE and Chrome).