# 401 Unauthorized accessing Web API withing Javascript

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dns, active-directory, http-status-code-401

I have  web api that uses windows authentication. I've created my own Active Directory Server and a separate IIS Server. I have registered the IIS server to the domain but for some reason I'm getting a 401 issue when I use the API URL in my Javascript.

[image]

But works when using it directly from web browser

[image]

Please note that this is the same code (javascript, SQL Server, and ASP.NET Web Api) I'm developing at work. The only difference are the url for LDAP and domain. I have tried everything from changing Windows Authentication Providers. I'm just curious if I need to add my machine as a trusted to the Active Directory which I'm not sure how. I have added the Active Directory User to the IIS with Full Control but still no luck.

Comment: I answered this a little while ago here: [Keep on getting Unauthorize Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390738/keep-on-getting-unauthorize-web-api). I'm pretty sure you have exactly the same thing going on.

Comment: I just realized that was your question too! Why did you post again? It's the same issue.

Comment: I don't  think this is code related Gabriel. As explained, the same code works (except the domain url) when I run it in our work domain. I have compared the setting of my IIS server at work and IIS server at home and they are identical. I have a gut feeling I'm missing some Active Directory related configuration.

Comment: Is the domain name you are using for your API at home listed in the Trusted Sites (in the Internet Options) on your computer? Is the domain name you are using for the website at home in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header returned by the API?

Comment: Yes it is in the Trusted Sites. Not sure how to check Access-Control-Allow-Origin... Again the web api has the same code I use for the work domain so I didn't change anything there except the LDAP url, SQL Server and IIS server.

Comment: I described it in the answer I gave to your other question. If all the code is the same, but the domain name you use for the website is different, then that's the problem.

Comment: You said in the other question that you updated the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`. I described why it cannot work with `*` and it must match exactly to the domain you are using for your website.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for you patience. I have tried adding the url of the domain instead of * but still the issue.

Comment: What I meant with code are the same but domain name is different. As I have explained, I have created my own domain name at home and basically trying to run the same code except the domain names are different. instead of http://iisserver.workdomain.com I use http://iisserver.homedomain,com

Comment: Are there any other errors or warnings in the JavaScript console besides the 401 error?

Comment: Unfortunately none.